# PHP xpath search query

Tags: php, xpath

With help from another question I have used xpath to return queries from a website but I need it to search for specific titles.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.example.com");
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//span[@class='newprodtext' and contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'adidas')][1]");

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {

echo "Node($i): ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}

?>
```

This is a sample HTML:

```
<td colspan="2" align="center">
  <a href="product.html" style="text-decoration:none">
   <span class="newprodtext">Nike Shoes</span>
  </a>
</td>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
  <a href="product.html" style="text-decoration:none">
   <span class="newprodtext">Nike T-Shirt</span>
  </a>
</td>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
  <a href="product.html" style="text-decoration:none">
   <span class="newprodtext">Adidas Shoes</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

I need the search to look for two individual words such as if I was looking for "Adidas Shoes" I want the query to return TRUE but I also want it to return TRUE if it finds the reverse term "Shoes Adidas" or lowercase "shoes adidas" rather than exact string.

Comment: So you need to search for a list of classes? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Search for two words together? What do you mean? The only scrapable content in your sample HTML is "Product Title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your xpath to something like this:

`//span[@class='newprodtext' and contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'adidas shoes')]`

if you want the nodes containing your search word, and to this

```
translate(//span[@class='newprodtext']/text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='adidas shoes' or `translate(//span[@class='newprodtext']/text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='shoes adidas'
```

if you want a T/F response. There's two differing methods here, one using `contains()` and one using just `translate()`. If you want an exact matching of 'adidas shoes' and 'shoes adidas' then use the latter solution. If you are just looking for 'adidas', use the first solution and apply the same change made for the latter if you want T/F.

**Update:**
If you want *just* the first node with "adidas", then use this:

```
//span[@class='newprodtext' and contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'adidas')][1]
```

And if you want it in T/F wrap a `boolean(//span[@class='newprodtext' and contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'adidas')][1])` around it. If you do happen to need additional search words, copy and paste the contains() part back in, and change adidas to the word(s).

Comment: Brilliant thats almost what I need except I need it to see the words no matter what the format is e.g. "shoes adidas", "new shoes (adidas), "adidas (2012 edition shoes)". Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, and yes that makes sense. The translate() will take care of the casing, are you looking for just anything with "adidas" or those exact lines?

Comment: actually if I can limit the xpath result to the first of "adidas" it finds then I wont need to add more than one search word, how would I limit to only the first node?

Comment: This doesn't work when using
`foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
 
    echo "Node($i): ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}` how should I show it...sorry xpath really goes over my head

Comment: I wasn't sure how you were using the XPath, might want to add the foreach in your question for reference. Are you using the results from my provided XPath in place of "nodes" there?

Comment: not sure why it's not displaying anything for you, I tested the xpath on the snippet you provided, and got back "Adidas Shoes"... try it without the [1] and see if that does anything