# Making xPath into a variable

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

How do I turn the output into a variable so i can cross reference it to see if it matches another variable I have set

```
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

I know this is incorrect and wouldn't work but:

```
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
  $target = $node->nodeValue;
}

$match = "some text"

if($target == $match) {
  // Match - Do Something
} else {
  // No Match - Do Nothing
}
```

Actually this solves my question but maybe not the right way about it:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.example.com");
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("(//tr/td/a/span[@class='newprodtext' and contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'adidas')])[1]");
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {

echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
$target[0] = $node->nodeValue;
}

$match = "adidas";

if($target == $match) {
    // Match
} else {
    // No Match
}
```

Comment: see: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xpathphp/index.html

Comment: Your XPath is usually just a query string. You likely mean the result of an XPath Query, which will be an array of SimpleXmlElements when using SimpleXML or a DOMNodeList when you use DOM. You have to compare those manually.

Comment: Into which concrete problem do you run? How to assign that nodeValue to a variable in PHP?

Comment: I've added more to my question to better explain it, so this can't be done in the same php script?

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do? your question makes little sense, why are you reassigning always the last node to $target, why is the if not inside the loop and what is it that you want to do if you match or not...

Comment: ive updated it again to clarify what i'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is more about general understanding of loops, assigning values to arrays and using *if* conditionals with php than using xpath.

- In your foreach loop, you're assigning each `$node`'s `nodeValue` to the same index in your `$target` array, `$target` will always have only one value (the last one)
- In your `if` conditional statement, you're comparing an `array` (or `null` if `$nodes` has no items, so you probably want to declare `$target` first) against the string 'adidas', that will never be true.

You probably want to do something like:

```
$matched = false;
$match = 'adidas';
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    $nodeValue = trim(strip_tags($node->textContent));
    if ($nodeValue === $match) {
        $matched = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($matched) {
    // Match
} else {
    // No Match
}
```

**Update**

I see that this xpath expression was given to you in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14122881/165969), that presumably already does the matching, so you just need to check the [length](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) property of `$nodes`

```
if ($nodes->length > 0) {
    // Match
} else {
    // No match
}
```